# Rails 5 use global methods in a form that doesn't save the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I built two methods one to convert an entered date into an integer. Then converting an integer into a date (always returning the Monday).

Date into integer:

```
def week_number(user_date)
  start_date = Time.parse('Jan 6 2019 12:01')
  start_year = start_date.year
  alpha = Date.parse(user_date.try(:strftime, ("%B %e, %Y")))
  if alpha.year < start_year
   errors 'cannot be before 2019'
  elsif alpha.year > start_year
   beta = alpha.year - start_year
   over_current_year = beta * 52
   above_c = alpha.cweek + over_current_year
   above_c
  else
   alpha.cweek
  end
end
```

Integer into date (returning the Monday):

```
def week_date(user_number)
 start_date = Time.parse('Jan 6 2019 12:01')
 start_year = start_date.year
 if user_number < 1
  errors 'cannot be less than 1'
 elsif user_number > 52
  divided_number = user_number % 52
  year_return = start_year + divided_number
  date_return = Date.commercial(year_return, divided_number, 1)
  date_return.monday
 else
  user_return = Date.commercial(2019, user_number, 1)
  user_return
 end
end
```

So I'd like for these two methods to be available from anywhere in the application. How do I build out a form that would just hit these two methods without requiring a model?

What I've tried is throwing them in a TravelController, updated my routes to have:

```
root to: 'travel#index'
resources :travel do
 post :week_number, on: :collection
 post :week_date, on: collection
end
```

Then for the form did something like:

```
<%= form_with(url: week_number_travel_index_path, method: 'get', local: true) do %>
 <%= label_tag :user_date, 'Enter Date'%>
 <%= datetime_field_tag :user_date, nil, placeholder: Time.now.strftime("%b %e %Y %l:%M"), class: 'form-control' %>
 <%= button_tag 'Find Week Number', class: 'btn btn-success btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

So it should take the value from the input. What I'm struggling with is...is the right way to do it? How do I then display the value? I thought I could do <%=week_number(user_date)%> but I end up getting

> undefined local variable or method `user_date'

Comment: Where are you doing this `<%=week_number(user_date)%>`? your form does not show that. Also actions does not accept arguments (the route travel#week_number expects a method with no arguments). I think you want a view helper https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html but your description is really confusing, what's the actual use case for what you want that code? if you have an action that's called from a from, then the parameter `user_date` will by at `params[:user_date]` and not an argument of the method.

Comment: I was actually putting the <%=week_number(user_date%> in a div under the form. The goal is to have a form in which the user enters in a date (hence user_date) that then goes in the method and the result would be displayed below.

Comment: You are mixing some concepts of web development. From the code you show, it looks like that's something you want to do using just javascript right on the client instead of a request to the server. It makes no sense to have a form to call a rails action to call a ruby method on your server just to get a date when javascript can handle that. If you need something specific from the server then it's ok to make a request but you should read someting like this first https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: So doing client side form with JavaScript isn't really what I'm looking to do in the application. Maybe I should update the title to something like "building a form out of a Rails 5 tableless model". It's possible that we may actually store the data at some point so moving it to JS doesn't make sense.

Comment: What prevents you from submitting the data generated on the client side to the Rails controller later on ?