# Rails/JavaScript onclick send value through helper method, Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails method that is converting a date input and returning a number. I spent a bit of time creating it so I'd like to keep using it. The data is not being stored. What I'd like to do is create a simple JS input to take the data and send it through the method.

So in essence my method is something like:

```
def date_converter(user_number)
 blah blah blah
 if blah < 2069
  error
 els if blah > 2069
  convert user_number.year
 else
  this number
 end
end
```

Then in my HTML I have a basic JS input:

```
<p> Enter in Date </p>
<input id="check_number">
<button type="button" onclick="numberFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 function numberFunction() {
  var x, dispay_value;
  x = document.getElementById('check_number').value;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = display_value;
 }
</script>
```

So I would need to send x through the method and then send the result to the innerHTML. Using Ajax I updated my PostsController with the method but taking off the argument. I created a route:

```
post 'posts/date_converter' => 'posts#date_converter'
```

Then in my Post > Show I updated the script to have:

```
function numberFunction() {
 user_number = $('check_number').val();
 $.ajax({
     url: 'week_date',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'html',
     data: {
         number: user_number,
     }
 }).done(function(res) {
     $('#demo').html(res);
 });
}
```

I end up with

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=date_converter):

I thought it might be a route issue using Post so I tried with Get. Same issue. Attempted putting it in it's own partial and rendering the partial on the Post > Show and same issue.

Edit: So I made some additional changes. I kept the route as a get. Added to the ajax request:

> beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',
>   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}

I updated the controller to pull in the current post (@post = Post.find(params[:id])), even though I'd rather not tie it to a current post, and then updated the route to be:

```
get '/posts/:id/week_date' => 'posts#week_date'
```

So when I run it I get:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=posts)

If I change it the ajax request to a specific url like:

```
url: '1/date_converter'
```

Which is not what I want, I end up with

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `user_number'

So to sum up, if I use a specific ID in my ajax request - which is against what I'm wanting, then it's not even passing the value into the local variable.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you want to make a form submission do it the way you're doing it now. If you're saying you want to make an Ajax request that does *just* that then create a route that takes its input and returns the output, then make that request via (whatever Ajax mechanism you prefer) and process the results.

Comment: How do I pass the input on the JS to a rails method in a helper? There is no table/model on the Rails side. The method is just in a helper. So creating a rails form would require building that and a controller. Simply passing the input value into a method.

Comment: You can't. Unless you submit it to a controller action and into your helper method that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5 use global methods in a form that doesn't save the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979204/rails-5-use-global-methods-in-a-form-that-doesnt-save-the-data)

Answer (score 0):

You should be use ajax

Move function 'date_converter' to your controller

```
def date_converter
  number = params[:number]
  blah blah blah
  if blah < 2069
   error
  els if blah > 2069
   convert
  else
   this number
  end
end
```

Then, define date_converter path and get action from rails routes(example equal: users/date_converter) and create ajax to your js

```
function numberFunction() {
  dispay_value = $('check_number').val();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'users/date_converter',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
          number: dispay_value,
      }
  }).done(function(res) {
      $('#demo').html(res);
  });
}
```

Comment: Made a couple minor changes but gave this a shot. Looks like it's failing. Don't know if it's a controller issue or a route issue.

Comment: might be cors. I know it's same origin, but sometimes I need to set the csrf token in a `beforeSend`

Comment: So I added in the ajax: beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}. I updated the url to 'posts/1/date_converter'. Updated the route to get 'posts/:id/date_converter' and even put in a set_post method to pull in the post. Same issue.

Comment: @Jake "Same issue" as *what*?!

Comment: Valid question. I'll update the question with what steps I've done to make it clearer.